# how to center big image in a small div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with **264width/264height**

i need to put an image with **1600x1067** in the center of div

i don't know what is the best prattice

```
   <div style="width:264px;height:264px">
<img> <!-- img with 1600px / 1067px -->
</div>
```

Comment: possibly `<center>` tag (HTML), but that is kind of deprecated.

Comment: What do you mean by "center"?

Comment: I have one div with 264x264 

i need the image fit all the space, but don't attach, just fit width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.my-size {
    width:264px;
    height:264px;
    border:solid 1px #e1e1e1;
}

.full-bg { 
  background: url(https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/97054699/m=2048_k=1_a=1/5bd4a9ac205fef91437ee596edda9362) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class='my-size full-bg'></div>
```

Why not just set the image as the background and use background-size:cover to fill the [space like the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/d5oymfke/2/) or below example as well, the image in the example is actually 1600 x 1067 px as well.

```
background-size: cover;
```

This way, you are using less code, and also always filling the DIV entirely without distorting the image.

Answer (score 0):

From maintenance standpoint using styling in external style sheet is better, so put your DIV style in a .css file, like this:

```
div { width:264px; height:264px }
```

Make sure to assign ID or CLASS attribute the this DIV element or else all DIVs may end up of that size.

The image may be set in numerous ways. Due page loading speed I suggest to resize image in an editor (Illustrator, Photoshop...) to 264px X 264px, but doing so within the web page itself will do as well.

If you decide to re-size image within the web page, you have few options. With external .css (as I did with DIV above), with internal styles inside that page's header, as inline style (the way you showed us in your example) or with the HTML attributes WIDTH and HEIGHT. Unlike other styling that is suggested to be done via a CSS, the images width and height properties are better of by using those attributes. That is because a browser will re-size them to that value during loading and will not waste time calculating the relative width (in %) or loading it from external sheets.

**Centering:**

It is unusual to load place an image in a container with predefined size. It is a better practice to wrap an image within a DIV container with no WIDTH and HEIGHT assigned to it, but having it assigned to image only. In that way the image will expand the DIV as much as needed. For instance:

*CSS:*

```
 div { position:relative }
 img { position:relative; margin:0 auto; padding: 5px; }
```

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <img src="../whatever.jpg" width="254px" /> 
</div>
```

1. We left HEIGHT as is in order to preserve the ratio. If you do HEIGHT="264px" then your image stretches and gets distorted.
2. We shrank width to 254px and added padding of 5px; that will make your DIV end up 264px in width, with 5px padding on all 4 sizes far from the image border. The height of the DIV in this case will be 1067/1600 * 264px.

If you add a groove or ridge border, or perhaps a round one, you get really nice effects.

Here are some links that may (or may not :)) assist more in this matter:
http://www.brenkoweb.com/tutorials/html/html-images-and-media/img-tag.php
http://www.brenkoweb.com/tutorials/css/css-advanced/calculating-widths-and-margins.php

Comment: this don't work! 

the image fit just 100% width, but not the height! i need the image fill all the space, but don't distort

Comment: Have you by accident made the DIV's height 264px as well?

Comment: I just now tested:                                                                                                               <style type="text/css">
 div { position:relative }
  img { position:relative; margin:0 auto; padding: 5px; border:3px ridge red; }
</style>

<div>
    <img src="image.png" width="254px" />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox for life :)

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm

No reason not to use the latest and greatest in CSS.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Although if you want it to always cover the full area use the cover method mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
       <img> <!-- img with 1600px / 1067px -->
      </div>

      .thumbnail_wrapper{
          width:264px;
          height:264px;
       }
       .thumbnail_wrapper img{
          display:block;
          margin:auto;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a snippet of what it is, shows the body at color #efefef, then img div at Gray, and the image in the middle of the Gray div.

```html
    <style>
    .Box {width:50%;height:auto;background:gray;position:relative;}
    body {height:100%;width:100%;background:#efefef;}
    html {height:100%;width:100%;}
    .ImgDiv { width:264px;height:264px;position:relative;background:#efefef;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; }
    .Img { width:264px;height:264px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:static; }
    </style>
<body>
<div class="Box">
    <div class="ImgDiv">
    <img class="Img" src="https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/nature-hd-background-9.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)